# Mysql Full Text Index combining phrase and wild card

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

When using the mysql full text index search is it possible to combine both the phrase and wild card search.

Example:
In the database we have the following location name "Sydney Harbour".
We want to return a result when searching for "Sydney H".

I have tried :

```
SELECT 
  displayname 
FROM 
  Locations 
WHERE 
  MATCH(displayname)  AGAINST('"Sydney H"'* IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

However it does not work. Is it possible to combine both the phrase and wild card search?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SELECT displayname FROM Locations WHERE MATCH(displayname)
AGAINST('Sydney H' IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0
HAVING displayname LIKE '%Sydney H%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    displayname 
FROM 
    Locations 
WHERE 
    MATCH(displayname) AGAINST('+Sydney +H*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```